# Keep Running a tweepy stream for a long time

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I'm running a python script that is supposed to listen tweets with a specific '@' (and then execute some code).
My code is almost running 100% correctly but I still have an issue: my program stops running at random time for "no reason".
Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 551, in _get_chunk_left
    chunk_left = self._read_next_chunk_size()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 518, in _read_next_chunk_size
    return int(line, 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 583, in _readinto_chunked
    chunk_left = self._get_chunk_left()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 553, in _get_chunk_left
    raise IncompleteRead(b'')
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 436, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 518, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 454, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 488, in readinto
    return self._readinto_chunked(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 599, in _readinto_chunked
    raise IncompleteRead(bytes(b[0:total_bytes]))
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(292 bytes read)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 133, in <module>
    myStream.filter(track=['@DownDropship'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 474, in filter
    self._start(is_async)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 389, in _start
    self._run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 320, in _run
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 289, in _run
    self._read_loop(resp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 339, in _read_loop
    line = buf.read_line()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 200, in read_line
    self._buffer += self._stream.read(self._chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 540, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 454, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError("Connection broken: %r" % e, e)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(292 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(292 bytes read))
```

Here is a piece of my code:

```py
    from tweepy import StreamListener
    from retrying import retry
    import tweepy

    @retry
    class MyStreamListener(StreamListener):


        @retry
        def on_status(self, status):
            do something ...
            except Exception as e:
                pass

    myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
    myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth=twitter_handler.api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
    myStream.filter(track=['@Something'])
```

I found these "@retry" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839474/keeprunning-restarting-a-python-script-twitterapi) but apparently, it doesn't work properly.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I was getting a similar error when my storage maxed out (not using tweepy but during multiprocessing files). It's not clear what the rest of your code is doing or how you are managing the data when it comes in but perhaps profile your memory and storage in your code. Just a thought...

Comment: The code listen to tweets, save the first image in the tweet into a local directory. Then it reverse search the image on google, take the first result and then put the link in a new tweet (in answer to the first tweet). 
I hope it’s clear, how coule I profile my memory and/or storage?

Comment: you can look at something like this: https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/  but googling will come up with other options as well.

Comment: Hi again @JonathanLeon, I listened to what you suggested but it seems not to be the origin of the issue. My program uses 32Mb of RAM for 3.5 hours. Quick link : https://i.imgur.com/Bzmc5Yb.png
Any idea?

Comment: I poked around in the github issues: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/908 if you read through this and several others it may give you some thoughts on how to add some exception coding.